# Show that Turing recognizable languages are closed under intersection.

Tags: computational-complexity, formal-languages, turing-machines

The question ans its answer is given in the following picture:

[image]
[image]

But it is not clear for me what if one of the machine loops and the other rejects, will the TM describing the intersection reject also? I feel that the answer is not clear in that case.

Also what if the 2 machines loop, will the given machine loop?

Comment: I don't think $M_1$ and $M_2$ run simultaneously. $M_1$ runs first. Only if it acccepts will $M_2$ run. If both accept, $M$ accepts. If not, then $M$ loops (because either $M_1$ or $M_2$ loops) or rejects (in case both rejected).

Comment: yes they run respectively or alternatively @tobwin

Comment: Clearly if both machines loop, $M'$ can only loop.  How would it know what to do instead?  If one of $M_1$, $M_2$ rejects, it's easier to have $M'$ reject right away, but it could "wait for the other machine to finish."  If the slower machine halts, however, $M'$ must reject.  So, it might as well reject right away.

Comment: @tobwin: $M_1$ does not run first. They run pseudo-simultaneously, meaning that you do: step 1 of $M_1$; step 1 of $M_2$; step 2 of $M_1$; step 2 of $M_2$... Here it is not so critical, But if you wanted to compute the union and $M_1$ looped while $M_2$ accepted, you would never know about the latter with sequential simulation. However, the input should be accepted.

Comment: @PeterLeupold: To recognize the union means that $M$ must always accept if both $M_1$ and $M_2$ accept. Running $M_1$ and $M_2$ sequentially achieves that.

Comment: @tobwin The two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ may contain words $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that $M_1$ accepts $w_1$ while $M_2$ loops on it, and, conversely, $M_2$ accepts $w_2$ while $M_1$ loops on it.  If $M$ is to recognize the **union** of the two languages, and it runs $M_1$ and $M_2$ sequentially, in either order, then $M$ cannot accept both $w_1$ and $w_2$ as it should.

Comment: Of course, I was working with the intersection. Sorry!

Comment: @tobwin Also, the screenshot explicitly proposes that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are run pseudo-simultaneously, and there is no reason to confuse the issue by discussing a different solution that OP is not asking about.

Comment: My apologies! The phrasing "alternatively step by step" was simply not as clear to me. And given that the question asks about the intersection, I interpreted it to mean the "simpler", sequential variant. I did not mean to cause confusion, though I see how I did now.

Comment: Right, the example with the union was wrong. Actually it is the very case of the intersection where the interweaving is essential.

Comment: @PeterLeupold: are you sure? I think interweaving is essential for the union, and not for the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If either of these two halts and rejects, $M'$ rejects." This answers your first question. If one of the machines loops and the other rejects, then you only simulate the looping one until the other one provides you with the rejection; after that the decision is clear (rejection) and there is no point in continuing the simulation, no matter what the other machine does (loop, accept, reject).

And yes, if both do not stop, then the new machine will not stop either but continue to simulate one step of the first, one of the second, one of the first etc. This is what alternating means. It is the most simple case of a technique called [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)), which is used to simulate several processes in the case where some possibly do not stop, and thus sequential simulation could possibly get stuck on the first process without ver touching the other ones.

By the way: the term "to loop" is a bit misleading here. It suggests that the machine keeps doing the same over and over. However, it can compute forever without repeating configurations and even without repetiton on a more abstract level.